# Why does the VBA dim statement act differently depending on the number of variables declared?

Tags: vba, variables

Why does VBA convert a long variable type into an integer if I declare more than 2 variables at once?
The following tests result in long variables in the first 2 cases, but an integer type in the 3rd.

```
Sub VarTest()
    Debug.Print "==Test1=="
    Dim j As Long: j = 1
    Debug.Print "j is: " & VarType(j)
End Sub
Sub VarTest2()
    Debug.Print "==Test2=="
    Dim i, j As Long: j = 1
    Debug.Print "j is: " & VarType(j)
End Sub
Sub VarTest3()
    Debug.Print "==Test3=="
    Dim i, j, k As Long: j = 1
    Debug.Print "j is: " & VarType(j)
End Sub
```

Comment: That's just how it works. `Dim i, j, k As Long` is the same as `Dim i As Variant, j As Variant, k As Long` - It is not a shortcut for defining them all as `Long`. It uses `Integer` in your case because the `Variant` is converted to the smallest needed type based on the value you put in it.

Answer (score 2):

In VBA, when you declare

```
Dim a, b, c As Long
```

is equivalent to this:

```
Dim a As Variant, b As Variant, c As Long
```

You can do like this to declare all the variable as Long:

```
Dim a As Long, b As Long, c As Long
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. I thought that I had seen that Syntax in the documentation, but I must have been looking at Visual Basic rather than VBA.

Comment: In Visual Basic is the same... In fact VBA means Visual Basic for Applications...

Comment: @Brutus here you can see documentation to declare variable in VBA: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/declaring-variables

Answer (score 0):

The type of each variable must be specified separately. If variable Type is not specified, it is `Variant` by default.

```
' AnyValue and MyValue are declared as Variant by default with values 
' set to Empty. 
Dim AnyValue, MyValue 

' Explicitly declare a variable of type Integer. 
Dim Number As Integer 

' Multiple declarations on a single line. AnotherVar is of type Variant 
' because its type is omitted. 
Dim AnotherVar, Choice As Boolean, BirthDate As Date
```

You can use [Deftype statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/deftype-statements) if you want.

Sample:

```
DefLng I-Z
Sub VarTest3()
    Dim i
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim s As String
    Debug.Print "a is: " & VarType(a) 'variant
    Debug.Print "i is: " & VarType(i) 'long
    Debug.Print "j is: " & VarType(j) 'long
    Debug.Print "k is: " & VarType(k) 'integer
    Debug.Print "s is: " & VarType(s) 'string
End Sub
```

Result:

```
a is: 0
i is: 3
j is: 3
k is: 2
s is: 8
```